# Android - Realm objects

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

**UPDATED:**

I created a new class, check the complet code:
TEST Class:

```
import org.parceler.Parcel;

import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.TESTRealmProxy;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@Parcel(implementations = {TESTRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = {TEST.class})
public class TEST extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    int Id;

    String Name;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public TEST(){

    }

    public TEST(int id, String name){
        this.Id     =   id;
        this.Name   =   name;
    }
}
```

Activity1:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        TEST dd = new TEST(2, "pa7");
    Log.e(TAG, "Profile: "+dd.getId());
        resultIntent.putExtra("userProfile",Parcels.wrap(dd));
        startActivityForResult(resultIntent, 3);
```

NewActivity:

```
TEST mUserd    = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("userProfile"));


        if(mProfileUserd != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ID:  USER: " + mUserd.getId()+" - name "+mUserd.getName());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Is Null");
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Profile: 2
 ID:  USER: 0 - name null
```

**OLD**

User class:

```
@Parcel(implementations = {
        UserRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = {User.class})
public class User extends RealmObject  {

    int Id;

    String Name;

}
```

Function:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("userProfile",Parcels.wrap(User.class, mAuthor));
        startActivityForResult(resultIntent, 6);
```

NewActivity:

```
 mUser    = Parcels.unwrap((Parcelable) getIntent().getExtras().get("userProfile"));
```

I have my Object called User, everything works okay besides one thing. I have one fragment(B) that request users from database but I don't need to save that users in realm. The only thing that I need in this fragment is send to another activity the user object.

Note: In other fragment (A) I do need save the users but in fragment B I don't.

My question: Do I need to create another Object called "User2" or something that not extends RealmObject and use in fragment B? Or there is another way.

```
 public class User extends RealmObject  {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1.) save to DB and query based on ID

2.) use [Parceler library and implement Parcelable](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler)

```
@Parcel(implementations = { UserRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { User.class })
public class User extends RealmObject {
    // ...
}

compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5"
apt "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5"
```

To [parcel RealmList, use following code](https://gist.github.com/patloew/bc32a2a1a3c0097e9c7020192fb2c78f)

```
/* Copyright 2016 Patrick Löwenstein
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License. */

public class RealmListParcelConverter implements TypeRangeParcelConverter<RealmList<? extends RealmObject>, RealmList<? extends RealmObject>> {
  private static final int NULL = -1;

  @Override
  public void toParcel(RealmList<? extends RealmObject> input, Parcel parcel) {
    if (input == null) {
      parcel.writeInt(NULL);
    } else {
      parcel.writeInt(input.size());
      for (RealmObject item : input) {
        parcel.writeParcelable(Parcels.wrap(item), 0);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public RealmList fromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
    int size = parcel.readInt();
    RealmList list = new RealmList();

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
      Parcelable parcelable = parcel.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
      list.add((RealmObject) Parcels.unwrap(parcelable));
    }

    return list;
  }
}
```

Normally I'd tell you to just `copyFromRealm()` and send it over, but you have to somehow serialize it anyways, and you'll need `Parcelable` for that.

**EDIT:** Okay I've tried and tested the following:

```
@Parcel(implementations = { PostRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { Post.class })
public class Post extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String text;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

public void startNextActivity(View view) {
    Log.i("MAINACTIVITY", "START NEXT ACTIVITY");
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setId(41274);
    post.setText("Blaaaaaah");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("post", Parcels.wrap(post));
    startActivity(intent);
}

public class SecondActivity
        extends RealmActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //...
        Post post = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("post"));
        Log.i("SECOND", "" + post.getId());
        Log.i("SECOND", "" + post.getText());
    }
}
```

Output says:

```
09-05 23:54:09.343 12085-12085/com.zhuinden.realmdatabind I/MAINACTIVITY: START NEXT ACTIVITY
09-05 23:54:09.383 12085-12085/com.zhuinden.realmdatabind I/SECOND: 41274
09-05 23:54:09.383 12085-12085/com.zhuinden.realmdatabind I/SECOND: Blaaaaaah
```

Comment: I'll check this and post again. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I added parcel implementation to my class. Is just 1 object so I don't think that I need RealmListConverter. Anyways, now how can I send the object to another activity? Should be like;: 
        resultIntent.putExtra("user", (Parcelable) mAuthor);

Comment: I readed this: To use your @Parcel annotated objects as a Parcelable, you have to wrap them by Parcels.wrap(object). To get your original object from a Parcelable call  Parcels.unwrap(parcelable). So what I did: 
        resultIntent.putExtra("user", Parcels.wrap(mAuthor)); then in my other activity: mUser      = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("user")); ... But don't work, the object is empty

Comment: .... I haven't really used Parceler before, so I'll only be able to check this issue when I get home. What happens if you don't specify the proxy in Parceler as the class, and you use realm.copyFromRealm(mAuthor) with Parcels.wrap?

Comment: I got this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RealmObject is not valid, so it cannot be copied.

Comment: Ah right, you are not saving the data in the Realm, so it cannot be managed, which means it cannot be copied out. In that case however I do not see why parcelling didn't work. Can you verify that your User wasn't empty in the first place? Worst case scenario, just make a new class that's not a RealmObject and copy over...

Comment: Yeah, isn't empty becuase I already tested that. Making a new class isn't bad practice? What do you think?

Comment: Try updating to Parceler 1.1.5 first

Comment: I'm already using this; 
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.5'
    apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'

Comment: I'll need to get home from the store and then check parcelling an unmanaged realm object. It'll be like an hour though..... Wait a second, do you have getters/setters? If you don't, remove the serialization strategy bean

Comment: Yes, I have getters/setters. I tried this ; 
@RealmClass
@Parcel(analyze = {User.class})

        /*(  implementations = {
        UserRealmProxy.class},
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = {User.class})*/  --- I removed implementations and just use analyze and now is working, do you know why?

Comment: Not sure. I've tried it as specified and it works for me, just like that. (check edit)

Comment: I have the same besides extends RealmActivity { what is that?

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. I forgot 1 getter so thats why I was getting empty object